# MySQL table charset issues when moving servers

Tags: character-encoding, mysql

I am trying to move phpBB's database from one old server to another new one.

Old server is running MySQL 5.0.45 with phpMyAdmin 2.8.0.2.
New one is running MySQL 5.5.17 with phpMyAdmin 3.4.3.2.

Old server's default charset is UTF-8, but phpBB's database is all in latin1 and latin1_swedish_ci collation. As it is polish forum, it has polish accents in words in it and although they display correctly on the forum, phpMyAdmin shows them as:

- **ć** is displayed as **æ**
- **ś** - **¶**
- **ż** - **¿**
- **ł** - **³**
- and so on...

I got two dumps of the database, one from phpMyAdmin available on the server and the second one done by server's admin using mysqldump. My guess is that dump is done in utf-8 format, but in a way that prevents me from importing the dump to the new database and keeping polish accents. E.g. UTF-8's hex value for letter **ć** is `C4 87`, while in both dumps hex value for the letter is `C3 A6`.

So, how do I go about it? What do I do to import the dump (or export correctly if that's the problem) so it preserves polish accents?

Maybe I should convert the dump somehow? I tried using iconv with no success, but I have next to none experience with it.

Oh, and by the way, the forums html charset is iso-8859-2, which is correct for displaying polish accents.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your server, you can change the default encoding for your new server in my.cnf file.

```
[mysqld]

default-character-set=latin1

default-collation=latin1_german1_ci
```

and if you use command line to perform import you can use this command

```
mysql -h host -u username -p password -default_character_set utf8 database < file.sql
```

Comment: No, unfortunately I have no shell access to any of the servers. Neither old nor the new one. The only way I can interact with MySQL is via phpMyAdmin.

Comment: hhmm.. in your db script, did you try specifying a charset for you columns and tables? chnage that and should work.

Comment: What do you mean by "my db script"? Charset is included in the exported files, so the same db/table/column charset is used when importing.

Comment: the sql file that gets generated when you perform a mysqldump from the old server.

Comment: phpMyAdmin doesn't allow such thing. I might be able to get old server's admin to specify that, but which do you think I should tell him to use?